# Displaying hstore saved values in form for input when editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, hstore

I got a problem with displaying saved values in form_for for hstore data (filters).
It's saved in database but when I'm going back to this view to edit something I can't see actual values in input form fields like in normal form_for without hashes.

This is shorcut of me view code

```
<%= form_for @lesson, url: { action: "step3" }  do |f| %> 
    <%= f.fields_for :filters do |d| %> 
        <%= @lesson.filters["age_from"] %> # like this value would be displayed
        <%= d.text_field :age_from %>
        <%= d.text_field :age_to %>
        <%= d.text_field :name %>
        <%= link_to "Back", step1_lesson_path(@lesson) %>
        <%= submit_tag "Next" %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try with changing the view a bit, passing `@lesson.filters` in `fields_for` as following

```
....
  <%= f.fields_for :filters, OpenStruct.new(@lesson.filters) do |d| %>
    #your code goes here ...
  <% end %> 
....
```

Comment: It should work, can you re-check your associations and action in controller that return instance variable.

Comment: Ok, it works, but i also had to add  @lesson.filters = OpenStruct.new(@lesson.filters) to my controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without modifying controller action:

```
<%= f.fields_for :filters, OpenStruct.new(@lesson.filters) do |d| %>
```